# Is shaking a phone enough energy to charge a smartphone?

Tags: energy, kinematics, electric-circuits, electric-current

Is shaking a phone enough energy to charge a smartphone? For example I'd like to use some kind of power generator to charge smartphone's battery but I'm wondering if shaking (by hand, or motion when phone is in pocket while walking or on bike) is even enough to generate enough electric power to start charging.

Comment: Have you looked whether or not such charging devices exist right now? (hint: yes, they do)

Comment: Would [Electrical Engineering SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) be a better home for your question?

Comment: Thanks for those 2 answers: I didn't check if those exist already and indeed I see they do, however I'm wondering if those actually works. And http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ is rather not the place as I don't want go into details I was just wondering from physics point of view.

Comment: Why would you expect that a *chemical* based battery could be charged via vibrations? Or are you thinking of *making* a charger a la watched charged by motion

Comment: Can one charge a smartphone by shaking? Yes? Should one look like a mad person in public? No.

Comment: @CuriousOne actually I was thinking of way to have my phone be charged while riding a bike, no by hand

Comment: There are plenty of nice dynamos available.